# Jquery email validate in existing code

Tags: jquery, validation, email

I am new to jquery and have been fiddling with this code for a bit now.

Essentially its a validation script that checks to see if there is two or more characters in a field. If yes, it does its thing - if not, it shows ( on the page, a div/h2 tag with an error message )

All is good as far as text fields go, but the email field.... well...

> if (email = '' || email.length <= 2) { 
>           valid += '<p><span>X</span>Your Email ' + required + '</p>';
>   }

All it does is check to see if there are characters in the field.

I've been through lots of different types of regex's trying to get a validation going where it checks for the @ in the address and will use the existing span to show an error.

Is it possible? within the framework of what I have?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

======
In your case

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

if (!regex.test(email)) { 
    valid += '<p><span>X</span>Your Email ' + required + '</p>';
}
```

Comment: You are adding another function as far a my limited knowledge goes - I think it needs to be an "if" statekment so it will run within the existiong source

Comment: yes you can i just provided an example you can use the same in if block

Comment: Oh my-- that appears to work are you up for one other thing??

Comment: What I did was wrap the entire thing in a div and id'd it with #showit and a class in css to show it,then at the end of the function on success, I added a $('form #showit').hide(); so it hides the form after successful submit.
now it appears that the client wants radios, checkboxes and a drop menu - I can add all of them to the fom,  but again - the validation :)

All I need is a sample and I'm pretty sure I can run with it

Comment: if possible just create a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ so I can change it as required.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do that but because there are so many other associated files that go with it css/js.... I cant get it operational - however I could zip it all up for you if you want